# How to Schedule a task to run every 30 minutes but only during working hours?

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I want a Windows Task to run every 15 minutes but only during the day and only during the week. Is this possible on the Task Scheduler? I have set it up like this:

[image]

But I am not sure if that's correct. I think it might end up stopping either at the end of the first week or at the end of the first day after those 12 hours expire?

Answer (score 1):

**Your configuration is sound**, but only time will tell! Good luck!